# ActiveRecord join tables with Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How to execute the query above using Ruby ActiveRecord?

```
SELECT p.name, c.ios FROM public.projects p
INNER JOIN public.controls c
ON c.company_id = p.company_id
```

I tried

```
Project.includes(company::controls)
Project.joins(:company => controls)
```

But all failed

```
Project Model: { id, name, company_id, type, created_at, updated_at }
Company Model: { id, name, created_at, updated_at }
Control Model: { id, ios, android, macos, company_id, created_at, updated_at}
```

Comment: Could you post your Project, Company and Control models?

Comment: @emilianolch I edited the question with the models

Comment: Post your model classes, so we can see how associations are declared.

Comment: @rafaelgara what exact error you are getting when you use `Project.joins(company: :controls)`? Ideally, this should join the tables the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an INNER JOIN you need `table1: :table2`, assuming your models are correct you need the following

```
Project.includes(company: :controls)
Project.joins(company: :controls)
```